# Table Variable scoped to a single request, in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know this is probably a newbie question, but I have some issues understanding the *scope* of a Table Variable using SQL Server, in relation to a *simple query* performed in an application (no stored procedure, no function).

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/table-transact-sql), I can read :

> A table variable behaves like a local variable. It has a well-defined
>   scope. This is the function, stored procedure, or batch that it is
>   declared in.

I use SQL Server in a Node.js application, using the `raw()` functionality of a [Knex](http://knexjs.org/) client. I think Knex uses the [node-mssql](https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql) package and ultimately [Tedious](http://tediousjs.github.io/tedious/) to perform the requests. A connection pool is created when the Knex client is initialized.

So let's say I run this query using Knex, inside a transaction :

```
await knex.raw(`
  DECLARE @emailIdsToDelete TABLE(id int NOT NULL);

  INSERT INTO @emailIdsToDelete
  SELECT id
  FROM ...;

  DELETE organisations_emails
  FROM @emailIdsToDelete etd
  INNER JOIN ...;

  DELETE emails
  FROM @emailIdsToDelete etd
  INNER JOIN ...;
`);
```

Here, what is the scope of `@emailIdsToDelete`?

Will the table be deleted once this specific query is over (this is what I want) or will it exists as long as the connection is alive in the connection pool?

How can I make sure the table only exist in the scope of that specific request?

Should I use a "`GO`" keyword at the end, to remove it?

Comment: Why have you chosen to use a table variable and not a temp table? Table variables have their place, but in *most* cases a temp table is more appropriate?

Comment: @alroc No idea, to be honnest! I'm new to SQL Server. I need the fastest, more ephemeral table possible. What do you suggest?

Comment: I almost always opt for a temp table over a table variable. Why the preoccupation with speed (and speed of what, exactly? Creation? Execution? Populating with data?), and have you tested both methods to see if it makes a difference? Don't assume a table variable is faster - you need evidence.

Comment: As I said, I have no idea... and by the way this is why I'm asking here. I though table variables were only in memory so would probably be faster. Did *you* tested both? Your conclusion is that temp tables are in general faster? I'm interested by your results!

Comment: Table variables can spill into tempdb if they get big enough (they aren't purely in-memory), and temp tables (if small enough) are cached in memory (while the disk has to be written to at some point, SQL Server only interacts with data that's stored in memory so it'll be cached there). For my purposes (hundreds or thousands of rows and more than 1-2 columns), temp tables have major performance advantages over table variables. But as with anything else, you have to test with your data in your environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go

> GO is not a Transact-SQL statement; it is a command recognized by the sqlcmd and osql utilities and SQL Server Management Studio Code editor.

IOW, including `GO` in your statement will at best be pointless, and at worst will throw an error. In the code you provided, your table variable's scope will terminate when your request is completed.

In this case, the scope of the table variable is the batch that you're submitting to SQL Server within the `raw()` function and everything within it will go out of scope when the query(ies) complete. From http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187953(v=sql.105).aspx

> The scope of a variable is the range of Transact-SQL statements that can reference the variable. The scope of a variable lasts from the point it is declared until the end of the batch or stored procedure in which it is declared.

Comment: " your table variable's scope will terminate when your request is completed." Please explain... Links?

Comment: " I hope you're not concatenating strings" Don't worry about that! :-) Knex's "raw()" function still allows the use of bound parameters.

Comment: @electrotype not much else to explain. When your query completes and the request is no longer active, the table variable will longer be in scope and it'll evaporate.

Comment: Thanks for the help @alroc! You clearly know more than me! :-) But I wouln't mind understanding more... For example, why doesn't the table variable live as long as the connection? What are the actual  "stopper" making the the table being "evaporated"? The transaction's commit? Something else?

Comment: @electrotype From https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187953(v=sql.105).aspx: "The scope of a variable is the range of Transact-SQL statements that can reference the variable. The scope of a variable lasts from the point it is declared until the end of the batch or stored procedure in which it is declared." Your `raw()` call is one batch.

Comment: Thanks, I was't sure what a "batch" was.

Comment: Last "sub" question if you don't mind :-) You can see that, in my example, I run *two* `DELETE` queries based on the table created from a `SELECT`. I therefore can't use CTE (`with`), if I'm correct, since CTE support one query only. Knowing that, is my approach the fastest possible, in your opinion to run those two `DELETE`? Something else to suggest? Thanks so much!

Comment: @electrotype you should post that as a new question as it's beyond the scope of what you originally asked

Comment: You are right. Also, I would accept your answer if you copy some of the extra informations you added in the comments. As is, it doesn't answer my question about the *scope* fully! As you wish. Thanks!

Comment: New question posted : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49780324/sql-server-the-optimal-way-of-running-two-delete-statements-using-the-same-sel

Answer (score 1):

In the interest of full disclosure, I'm kind of a fan of exercising explicit control rather than relying on what the code "should do" or "normally does". Call me paranoid.

That said, issuing a GO to explicitly end your batch will ensure that your table variable goes away.

EDIT: But alroc is right. I was thinking in SSMS scripting, not a third party call. GO is probably useless.

Your other option, of course, is to use a temp table and, again, exercise explicit control over it.

```
CREATE TABLE #emailIdsToDelete (id int NOT NULL);
...<logic>...
DROP TABLE #emailIdsToDelete;
```

Comment: Srly. Did you just call me paranoid?

Comment: I'm looking for a small temporary table that will last only for the scope of ONE request. Is "CREATE TABLE" a good option for that?

Comment: For what you need, it's really a coin flip. There are a small number of cases where temp tables and table variables outperform one another, but it doesn't seem like you have anything weird going on. For a quick data dump, either is perfectly sufficient. It's nearly a personal preference thing in a case like you have here.

Comment: A Table Variable is in memory only right? How can't it be faster than a table that needs to be written to disk? (thanks for your help!)

Comment: Nope. :) You're in tempdb either way. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c82c63d3-d4f0-4dfd-936e-06445935021d/do-table-variables-use-tempdb?forum=transactsql

Comment: Edited, with a nod to @alroc.

Comment: @EricBrandt at least one significant difference: table variables don't get statistics, while temp tables do. In SQL Server prior to 2014, table variables are assumed to have one row; 2014+, the assumption is 100. This can (does) lead to very skewed estimates and bad query plans. I almost always opt for a temp table over table variables. See https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/04/table-variables-good-temp-tables-sql-2014/ for more.

Comment: BTW, the temp table will be dropped when the scope terminates, same as the table variable is. It doesn't *hurt* to drop it, but it's also not absolutely necessary.

Comment: @alroc, both are fair points. The stats are a difference. Whether it’s significant or not depends on the OP’s use case. On dropping the temp table, it’s that paranoia thing I mentioned. I can’t stop myself from doing it.